# What is the probability that there are more than two people from Z with the mutation.

Tags: probability

I don't know how to solve this one, need help :(

In a fictional country, it is estimated that 0.005% of the population has a mutation. Assuming this mutation is evenly distributed throughout the territory and knowing that the population of the Z city is about 1 million inhabitants, what is the probability that:

a) There are more than two people from Z with the mutation
b) There are more than 50 people with this mutation in Z (summation form and normal approximation)

I tried solving it like this:

P(X>2) = 1 - (P(X=0) + P(X=1) + P(X=2))
P(X>2) = 1 - (0.99995^1000000 + 0.99995^999999 * C(1000000, 1) * 0.00005^1 + 0.99995^999998 * C(1000000, 2) * 0.00005^2)

Is it the correct approach? The calculation gets very hard so I'm not sure

And about b), I don't know other methods to solve it other than what I did above and I'm pretty convinced that doing P(X=50) + P(X=49) + ... + P(X=0) isn't the way.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: @AnotherUser thanks for the info, edited it

Comment: If you find the answer below satisfactory, then please close your inquiry by clicking the green check mark. Thank you!

Comment: @sggus i updated my post to answer your specific questions a and b

Comment: @RyRytheFlyGuy extra thanks for the update, I forgot to check it as the answer yesterday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the random variable $X$ be the number of people with the mutation in a sample of $n$ people. Note that $X$ is a Binomial random variable with parameters $p,n$. Due to the uniform distribution of the mutation, the probability of selecting one mutated person at random from the city Z is $p = 0.005 $% $ = \frac{0.005}{100} = 0.00005$.

We wish to know the probability of selecting $n = 1,000,000$ people and finding $X > 2$ and finding $X > 50$. Note the expectation and variance of $X$ is given by $E[X] = np = 1,000,000 (0.00005) = 50$ and $Var[X] = np(1-p) = 49.9975$

Regarding $a$, you can indeed compute $P(X>2) = 1 - (P(X=0) + P(X=1) +P(X=2))$ where the exact probabilities are computed using the probability mass function (pmf) of a Binomial random variable, which is

$$ P(X=k) = {n \choose k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k} $$

Hence,

$P(X>2) = 1 - (P(X=0) + P(X=1) +P(X=2))$

$= 1 - \Big[{10^6 \choose 0} 0.00005^0 (1-0.00005)^{10^6-0} + {10^6 \choose 1} 0.00005^1 (1-0.00005)^{10^6-1} + {10^6 \choose 2} 0.00005^2 (1-0.00005)^{10^6-2}\Big]$

$= 1 - \Big[0.99995^{10^6} + 10^6 (0.00005) 0.99995^{999,999} + {10^6 \choose 2} 0.00005^2 0.99995^{999,998}\Big]$

$= 1 - \Big[1.92634034\cdot10^{-22} + 9.63218329\cdot10^{-21} + 2.40816382\cdot10^{-19}\Big]$

$= 1 - 0.00000000000000000001$

$= 0.99999999999999$

Regarding $b$, it would indeed be tedious to compute exact probabilities for $P(X=0), P(X=1), ..., P(X=50)$ using the pmf above. Fortunately, you can leverage the fact that, for large $n$, the probability distribution of the Binomial random variable $X$ becomes increasingly normal. Consequently, we can transform $X$ into a standard normal random variable $Z = \frac{X - E[X]}{\sqrt{Var[X]}} = \frac{X - 50}{\sqrt{49.9975}}$ with expectation $E[Z] = 0$ and variance $Var[Z] = 1$, and we can compute probabilities using the normal probability distribution. I outline how to solve $a$ and $b$ in this way below...

To answer questions $a$ and $b$, substitute $X=2$ and $X=50$, respectively; compute the corresponding Z-scores; and consult a standard normal curve table. Make sure you're finding the shaded area under the curve that corresponds to $1-F[Z]$ where $F[Z]$ is the cumulative distribution function of $Z$.

For $X=2$, we have $Z = \frac{X - 50}{\sqrt{49.9975}} = \frac{2 - 50}{\sqrt{49.9975}} = -6.79$. Hence, the $P(X>2) = P(Z > -6.79) \approx 0.99999999999$

In other words, the city Z is virtually guaranteed to have more than $2$ people with the mutation.

For $X=50$, we have $Z = \frac{X - 50}{\sqrt{49.9975}} = \frac{50 - 50}{\sqrt{49.9975}} = 0$, which is the mean of the distribution. Hence, the $P(X>50) = P(Z>0) \approx 0.5$